# How to make good Django model for custom template with dependencies with calendar days?

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-templates, django-views

I need to create model, which will save state of student (absent or present), and my output in template should be like this:
[image: My custom template with this table]

I have already done Student model, so I stopped on this model, because I don't even know how to design it to django.

I thought about making model like: id(foreign key to student id) and date. And output somehow with jquery or django template tags all days in specific months. Then when user press checkbox ajax sends creation of row with this student in this day. I'm not sure if it's right way.

So how make model with good quality code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is creating a model with a foreign key to `Student` and a date field, as you stated. Now, in order to make it work with your desired interface, yes, you will probably end up using AJAX calls to create the respective instances of the model. If you don't want to use AJAX you could generate your checkbox grid with convenient names, so that you can parse those names in the view and the bulk update all your models.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of a single `DateField` you could have a `IntegerField` for month, an `IntegerField` for year and then a `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` to store present days.